# How to convert list of TextSpans to a single text?

Tags: flutter, dart

For example I have a list of TextSpan:

`List<TextSpan> listTextSpan = [TextSpan(text: "Hello"), TextSpan(text: "World")];`

then:

```
AutoSizeText.rich(
 TextSpan(
  children: listTextSpan,
)),
```

So I want to make the list of TextSpan as a single text, That I'll be able to return

```
AutoSizeText.rich(
 TextSpan(
  text: singleText,
)),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fold method in order to combine every item on a list into a single value, the shape of the fold method looks like this:

```
var result = list.fold(initial, (previous, current) => result);
```

So in your case, if you just want to get a string of the text of every TextSpan, you would do it like this:

```
String singleText = listTextSpan.fold(
  '', 
  (prev, curr) => '$prev ${curr.text!}');
```

the initial value is an empty string and you take the previous value, which is the current string, and add to it a space and the text of the current TextSpan, also note that this will throw an error if one of your text spans does not have a text property, in order to avoid this, you must replace `curr.text!` to `curr.text ?? 'whatever you want'`

If you still have issues understanding how the fold method works, [you can check the documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/fold.html)